# fix error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Please

Tags: c#, dnp3, opendnp3

I have an issue with the code where I'm using 'IChannel' from Automatak.DNP3.Interface. How does it work? In my code, I encountered the error 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Here are the relevant parts of the code where the error occurred.Hope you can help me fix this error
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope you can help me fix this error

Comment: Please see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Looks like a bug. `AddOutStation` expects `AddTCPClient` to either throw or return a valid `channel` object.